# SQL Server : get value of @Columns_Updated

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger to find the updated columns and updated columns values during table update.

By using this, I can get the updated columns in the format of "col1,col2". The updated columns is separated by commas, which is good.

```
SELECT  
    @Columns_Updated = ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ', ', '') + name 
FROM    
    syscolumns 
WHERE   
    id = @idTable   
    AND CONVERT(VARBINARY,REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1) > 0

INSERT INTO Crm_Log 
    SELECT @Columns_Updated
--End of New Log
```

I want to ask how to find updated columns value provided that I already knew the updated columns name, it means that in the `UPDATE` trigger I have a `nvarchar` variable called `@Columns_Updated = 'col1,col2'`.

How can I find the updated values of col1 and col2 and put the result into another `nvarchar` variable `@Columns_Updated_Value` in format of `'wteveritis,32452'` (actually I don't care about the data type).

Update code provided:

```
DECLARE @Columns_Updated VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Columns_Updated_Values AS NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @CUV_temp TABLE(value NVARCHAR (500))   
DECLARE @sqlQuery AS NVARCHAR(200) = 'SELECT CONCAT(' + REPLACE(@Columns_Updated,',',','','',') + ') from inserted';

INSERT INTO @CUV_temp
    EXEC(@sqlQuery) 

SELECT @Columns_Updated_Values = value 
FROM @CUV_temp

INSERT INTO Crm_Log (ModifedFields, ModifiedValues) 
    SELECT @Columns_Updated, @Columns_Updated_Values
```

I get an error

> Invalid object name 'inserted'

when actually running the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use magic tables for this. Inside the trigger do this.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500); 
SELECT * into #t FROM INSERTED
SET @query = 'SELECT @Columns_Updated=  CONCAT(' + REPLACE(@Columns_Updated,',',','','',') + ') from #t';
EXEC sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition=N' @Columns_Updated nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @Columns_Updated = @Columns_Updated OUTPUT
SELECT @Columns_Updated
```

`INSERTED` magic table contains all the updated value of each column for the updated row. Declare your variable `@Columns_Updated` as `nvarchar`

Comment: hi, thanks but it didn't work:( the query end up with something like 'select rowId+clientId from inserted' (error would throw as int cannot + with string), the problem is rowId and clientId could be any type, i need to convert the udpated Column value into a single string separated by comma

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` function if you are using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: but then there is no separator between the fields

Comment: Updated query to include separator

Comment: thanks. it looks worked, i will try to apply and test it.

Comment: I should create a temp table @updated_Values_tab to store string?

Comment: Modified query to put result directly in your variable using system stored proc `sp_executesql`

Comment: Hi, i was trying the previous one. it is almost work, but it shows this error when i actually triggering the trigger. "Invalid object name 'inserted'.". i think it is because inserted is not accessible in execute query? should i try the new method? i have update my code, thanks

Comment: thanks. it worked. one last thing, can you tell me where I can find more information about #t? for example will there any overwritten issues when there are many triggers happened together?

Comment: a separate `#t` will be created for each connection. I don't think there will be a problem. It is a temporary table.